# Joda time - IllegalFieldValueException: Value 30 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,29]

Tags: java, jodatime, hijri

There is a call to some external system which returns a date in hijri. In Production env, we received it as `'30-02-1436'`.

Consider the snippet which converts the hijri to a gregorian date, but it fails to do so.

```
    public static String convertHijriToGregorianDate(String hijriDate){
        Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC(); // get the ISO standard chronology which we follow now
        Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC(); // the hijri based chronology
        //String hijriDate = "19-08-1435"; // example/format which is received as a parameter in the method from response

        if(null != hijriDate && !hijriDate.isEmpty()){
            String[] parts = hijriDate.trim().split("-"); // you will get an array of size 3 by splitting with regex '-'
            String hijriYear = parts[2];
            String hijriMonth = parts[1];
            String hijriDay = parts[0];

            // Construct the Local Date corresponding to the hijri chronology
            LocalDate todayHijri = new LocalDate(Integer.parseInt(hijriYear), Integer.parseInt(hijriMonth), Integer.parseInt(hijriDay), hijri);

            // Construct the Local Date corresponding to the iso chronology based on the hijri date
            LocalDate todayIso = new LocalDate(todayHijri.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(), iso);
            return String.valueOf(todayIso);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please suggest as to what is wrong with the code. We are getting this issue in stacktrace-

> org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 30 for dayOfMonth must
>   be in the range [1,29]
>                   at org.joda.time.field.FieldUtils.verifyValueBounds(FieldUtils.java:252)
>                   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.getDateMidnightMillis(BasicChronology.java:632)
>                   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.getDateTimeMillis0(BasicChronology.java:186)
>                   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.getDateTimeMillis(BasicChronology.java:160)
>                   at org.joda.time.chrono.LimitChronology.getDateTimeMillis(LimitChronology.java:177)
>                   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.getDateTimeMillis(BasicChronology.java:155)
>                   at org.joda.time.LocalDate.(LocalDate.java:457)

Joda time version used is `2.9.1`

Comment: @Tom: Its in Hijri and not in Greg. There is no month like Feb in Hijri

Comment: @Tom There are different variants. The website you cite is obviously different from umalqura calendar of Saudi-Arabis, compare also http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/ummalqura

Comment: @MenoHochschild Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked all available leap year patterns (=4) in Joda-Time by the expression

```
Chronology hijri = 
    IslamicChronology.getInstance(DateTimeZone.UTC, IslamicChronology.LEAP_YEAR_15_BASED);
```

Unfortunately nothing works for you. However, **the umalqura-calendar of Saudi-Arabia considers '30-02-1436' as valid**. It corresponds to the gregorian date 2014-12-22.

**Joda-Time does not support this variant of islamic calendar so you cannot do anything here unless you are willing to migrate to Java-8 which contains the umalqura-variant.**

```
System.out.println(HijrahDate.of(1436, 2, 30)); // Hijrah-umalqura AH 1436-02-30

DateTimeFormatter fh =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "dd-MM-yyyy",
        Locale.forLanguageTag("en")
    ).withChronology(HijrahChronology.INSTANCE);
System.out.println(HijrahDate.from(fh.parse(input))); 
// Hijrah-umalqura AH 1436-02-30
System.out.println(LocalDate.from(HijrahDate.from(fh.parse(input)))); 
// 2014-12-22
```

*Note: The unicode extension `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-u-ca-islamic-umalqura")` does unfortunately not seem to work in my experiments so specifying the chronology explicitly is necessary.*

**Alternative:**

If you cannot migrate to Java-8 or even need more features of islamic calendar (for example other variants like those used in Joda-Time) then you might also try out my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J):

```
String input = "30-02-1436";
ChronoFormatter<HijriCalendar> hf =
    ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
        "dd-MM-yyyy",
        PatternType.CLDR,
        Locale.ROOT,
        HijriCalendar.family()
    ).withCalendarVariant(HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA).with(Leniency.STRICT);
System.out.println(hf.parse(input)); // AH-1436-02-30[islamic-umalqura]
System.out.println(hf.parse(input).transform(PlainDate.axis())); // 2014-12-22
```

Comment: Thank you very much for devoting your time to the question. Its in production. I cant update to Java 8 and neither do I have the flexibility to switch to the cited library.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Understood, but you have really a serious problem, not just this single date with day-of-month=30. Every date of at least a whole month or more is shifted by one day. As (very) dirty work-around, you might consider to catch the exception and manually shift your dates to the desired gregorian dates (but I don't recommend it as durable solution).

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Maybe you should create your own umalqura calendar and use it instead of Joda. Studying the source code of Java-8 or [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/master/calendar/src/main/java/net/time4j/calendar/AstronomicalHijriData.java) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The date is interpreted as Feb 30, but this month must have fewer than 30 days in it. This explains the error message. So correct the input so it corresponds to a date that is possible.